# Sign in with apple on backend: how to authenticate subsequent calls

Tags: ios, jwt

I'm trying to understand the flow of "sign in with apple".
I found some examples in the internet but most of them are about making "authenticate" API endpoint which finds or creates user on the backend.

But how should I authorize the following API calls? My first guess was to use a custom auth token that backend generates after "authenticate" endpoint has validated successful sign in with apple.
Though I'm not sure if it's optimal because as I understand JWT is designed to be used without session tracking on the backend.

Also, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user) in the schema apple says "establish user session". What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Establishing and managing the user session is the responsibility of your server. Essentially the token you have obtained from Apple should be verified by your server and the user identifier extracted. Your server then sets up a user session, typically by issuing its own token. When your app calls your api it passes this session token.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. Just wanted to confirm that generation of a token on the backend is required.